# Django uploading files for user

Tags: django

I am able to upload the files in django. I have also managed to register different users.
But when the users log in , they all see the set of files that were uploaded by anyone.
instead I want the user views only those set of files which he/she has uploaded.

Here is my models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

views.py

```
def list(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponse("File Uploaded.. Kindly Refresh!!")
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'login/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

LIST.html

```
 <table cellpadding=20>
    {% for document in documents %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="delete/{{ document.docfile.name }}"> Delete</a></td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

  {% else %}
    <p>No documents.</p>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: add an `user`field to your `Document` model, then filter on that field in your view

Comment: Actually, I have set an owner in views.py, which sets the owner, but now what problem I am facing is that how do i filter the results in LIST.html for a specific user. Kindly help.

Comment: It stores the files as per the user logged in. now All i need to do is to filter the results for each specific user. Any help please.

Comment: Current user is `request.user`, filter `documents` against it and you've done, for example `documents = Documents.objects.filter(user=request.user)`. That's the reason why @J.Ghyllebert suggests to add an `user` field to `Document`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change models.py to this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

change views.py to this

```
def list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.user = request.user
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponse("File Uploaded.. Kindly Refresh!!")
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'login/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Comment: `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)` for `Django version 3.0.4`